# jndi properties not found

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new in Java.

Actually I'm on temurin-19.0.2 where I ddl this version directly on IntelliJ.

When I launch my project on Debug mode.
I always have *java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: myPath/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-19.0.2/Contents/Home/conf/jndi.properties*

And yes the *jndi.properties* is missing, not generated when I add the SDK.
When I search on internet about java.nio.file, It's already integrated on Java since Java 7 but for an unknown reason I have this problem.

Do you have any idea how can I resolve this problem ?
I don't find a great sample of jndi.properties file, so I don't how it looks like.

Comment: Java can not read a file that doesn't exists.  You should investigate first what to put in the file and where to put it, then create it yourself.